# Поиск ошибок в коде на C

Tags: c

Чем можно обнаружить наибольшее количество ошибок в коде еще на этапе компиляции?

Comment: А еще есть [PVS-Studio](https://www.viva64.com/ru/pvs-studio/), Coverity, PC-Lint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для gcc опция -Wall включает вывод всех предупреждений компилятора.

В MS VS в настройках проекта: configuration properties -> C++ -> General -> Warning Level ставим Level4

Есть специальные тулзины для строго анализа кода.

Например [cppcheck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cppcheck), [vera](http://www.inspirel.com/vera/)

Есть какие-то средства от парасофта - [static code analysis](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/solutions/cpp_solution.jsp?itemId=340#coding_std)

Comment: gcc -Wall -pedantic будет получше

Answer (score -1):

вопрос странный, компилятор выдает сообщения об ошибках в достаточном количестве, так же он выдает предупреждения по коду. 
Code::Blocks + MinGW прекрасно выдают ошибки, хотя местами одна ошибка тянет за собой кучу непонятных ошибок, которые исчезают после исправления первой :-D